# PHP Curl Web Scraping not returning the HTML

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I am trying to get the HTML contents from http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemVersion&item=324087765703

Here is my code

```
<?php

$lurl=get_fcontent("http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemVersion&item=324087765703");
print_r($lurl[0]);


function get_fcontent( $url,  $javascript_loop = 0, $timeout = 5 ) {
    $url = str_replace( "&amp;", "&", urldecode(trim($url)) );

    $cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );    # required for https urls
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close ( $ch );

    if ($response['http_code'] == 301 || $response['http_code'] == 302) {
        ini_set("user_agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1");

        if ( $headers = get_headers($response['url']) ) {
            foreach( $headers as $value ) {
                if ( substr( strtolower($value), 0, 9 ) == "location:" )
                    return get_url( trim( substr( $value, 9, strlen($value) ) ) );
            }
        }
    }

    if (    ( preg_match("/>[[:space:]]+window\.location\.replace\('(.*)'\)/i", $content, $value) || preg_match("/>[[:space:]]+window\.location\=\"(.*)\"/i", $content, $value) ) && $javascript_loop < 5) {
        return get_url( $value[1], $javascript_loop+1 );
    } else {
        return array( $content, $response );
    }
}

    ?>
```

This isnt returning anything, its empty for [0].

I found this function on SO. If there is a better function to use, im all ears...

Comment: You mean the control comes here `return array( $content, $response );`? I am getting the HTML just fine.

Comment: That URL is asking for a login on my part.

Comment: @vivek_23 if you keep running it, does it continue to work? im getting a limited HTML now with a META for norobots

Comment: What if you just used [https://www.ebay.com/itm/324087765703](https://www.ebay.com/itm/324087765703) as the URL?

Comment: @soldfor Makes sense because you are making continuous requests in less than a second. Don't do it too many times or else your IP can get blocked. Try adding a `sleep(2)` to create a lag of 2 seconds between requests.

Comment: @Jamie_D its not the same contents.